# Javascript character counter function with parameters

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, counter

I am beginner in javascript and I implemented to my EditorFor character counter found somewhere, here is how it looks in code now:

```
<span class="text-length-counter" id="email_counter"></span>                  
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfileFormDto.Email,  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control create-view-field", id="email_area" }})
```

And here is a javascript function that does the work:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      var text_max = 50;
      var text_length = $('#email_area').val().length;

      $('#email_counter').html(text_length +' / ' + text_max + ' znaków');

      $('#email_area').keyup(function() {
          var text_length = $('#email_area').val().length;

          $('#email_counter').html(text_length + ' / ' + text_max + ' znaków');
      });
  });
```

It is working fine, but I have to modify this function(), because I have to use many counters at one page, so function above have to take three arguments, like: Count(counter,area,max).I can't manage this. There is my new function declaration in  section:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        Count('email_counter','email_area',50);
    });

    function Count(counter,area,max) {

        var text_length = $('#area').val().length;

        $('#counter').html(text_length +' / ' + max + ' znaków');

        $('#area').keyup(function() {
            var text_length = $('#area').val().length;

            $('#counter').html(text_length + ' / ' + max + ' znaków');
        });
    };
```

It's not working, I get error:
Manage:169 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery selector is currently trying to select the elements with id="area" and id="counter"

If you're going to turn the area and counter into parameters, you need to select with $('#' + area)   and $('#' + counter).

With this update, your code would look like

```
function Count(counter, area, max) {
  var text_length = $('#'+area).val().length;

  $('#'+counter).html(text_length +' / ' + max + ' znaków');

  $('#'+area).keyup(function() {
    var text_length = $('#'+area).val().length;
    $('#'+counter).html(text_length + ' / ' + max + ' znaków');
  });
};
```

[Here's a working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qdawtx1/1/) with multiple input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector text is not correct.

```
Count('email_counter','email_area',50);

function Count(counter, area, max) {
    var text_length = $('#' + area).val().length;
    ...
    $('#' + counter).html(text_length +' / ' + max + ' znaków');
}
```